# SQL - Converting multiple rows into multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need a simple help here. Have went though various solutions such as using case and row number, pivot but unable to find a suitable solution.

Basically I want to use the group the Name values and find all the non null and distinct value and display the results in a single row.

Input

```
Name | Color
John | Blue
John | Green
Mary | NULL
Mary | Yellow
Mary | Pink
Mary | Pink
```

Expected Output

```
Name | Color1 | Color2 | Color3
John | Blue   | Green  |  NULL
Mary | Yellow | Pink   |  NULL
```

Currently I've came up to the query below but still looks far from my desired outcome. Appreciate your assistance , thanks!

```
select  Name,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then Color end) as Color1,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then Color end) as Color2,
    max(case when seqnum = 3 then Color end) as Color3
from (select table.*, row_number() over (partition by Name order by Name) as seqnum
    from table
    ) table
group by Name
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Using SQL server

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be using `DENSE_RANK` here, rather than `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rnk = 1 THEN Color END) AS Color1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rnk = 2 THEN Color END) AS Color2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rnk = 3 THEN Color END) AS Color3
FROM
(
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Name
        ORDER BY CASE WHEN Color IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, Color) rnk
    FROM yourTable
) t
GROUP BY
    Name;
```

[image]

### Demo

It isn't entirely clear what ordering you actually want to use for the colors, since in your expected output John's color are ascending while Mary's are descending.  I chose to order ascending, with `NULL`s last.

Comment: Thanks. I kind of understand the concept now. Issue is because the table is joined with multiple tables, currently figuring out how to include the join statements

Answer (score 0):

You could get the result as json like in the example:

```
SELECT concat(
    '{',
    name,
    ':[',
    GROUP_CONCAT(color),
    ']}'
) FROM `test` GROUP BY name
```

**Result:**

```
{
  John: [Blue, Green]
}
{
  Mary: [NULL, Yellow, Pink, Pink]
}
```

[**Demo**](https://sqltest.net/#320212)

Comment: Apparently OP is using SQL Server. Will this still work?